# What genre is Zac Brown Band's Mango Tree

Tags: identify-this-genre

I recently discovered a song by [Zac Brown Band called *Mango Tree* featuring Sara Bareilles](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UOBgmPwNF7I) and I am pretty nuts for the style.

I'd really like to know what genre this falls into, despite being a country artist it really isn't country. I'd lean towards Jazz / Big Band.

What genre best describes Mango Tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd also lean towards jazz/big band. It has a similar sound to the big band singers like Frank Sinatra, Dean Martin, Sammy Davis Jr., Bing Crosby, etc. Similar songs from that era would be:

- "[Summer Wind](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ug8cBIbxDaY)" by Frank Sinatra
- "[Ain't That A Kick In The Head](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xb4P-MZMzJs)" by Dean Martin
- "[Something's Gotta Give](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xb4P-MZMzJs)" by Sammy Davis Jr.
- "[Winter Wonderland](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zifGp5KTBKg)" by Bing Crosby

None of these are duets, but stylistically they're very similar otherwise, with heavy focus on the singer, swirling horns that come in and out, and a laid back feel.

Comment: Possibly a nod to Western Swing, because of ZBB's country roots, but I agree with the answer above